# In excel how do I highlight all rows that do not contain ",2"

Tags: excel

I'm verifying the FormatCurrency function is written properly in asp code and I put everything in excel from find results.  I want to highlight only the ones that do not contain ",2" in them.

```
**Don't hightlight this:** styResult = FormatCurrency(TotalCostOfOwnership, 2)
**Highlight this:**        strResult = FormatCurrency(TotalRevenueStream, 8, 3)
**Don't hightlight this:** styResult = FormatCurrency(TotalCreditsReceived,2)
```

Comment: Question belongs on superuser

Comment: What button do I have to push to move it their automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply conditional formatting to the cells in question (Format -> Conditional formatting), choose "Formula is", use `=ISERROR(FIND("2", A1))` as the formula and wisely choose your preferred colour.

Comment: OP is looking for a comma, optional space(s), then a 2  Maybe `=ISERROR(FIND("2", SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))`